# How to generate the auto populated template from docusign api

Tags: docusignapi

I have the template setup un the sandbox. Whenever I want to be redirected to demo.docusign.net and take action on the PDF, it is auto-populating the tabs. But my requirement is to simply **generate the PDF without redirecting to docusign on click of a button**. I am sending user information on click of a button to docusign and it has to generate the auto populated customer data on PDF for viewing (draft version). Currently it is generating the template without any dynamic user data, even though I pass the values. Please let me know, if there is any api to perform this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you're trying to do. But sounds like you want:

[1. Remote signing. Not Embedded Signing.](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-request-a-signature-via-email)

[2. Populate values of tabs in templates.](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/set-template-tab-values)

You also didn't specify which coding lang you used, so I'm going to give you some C#. You can find the full code examples in all langs in the links above.

```
        // Step 1: Obtain your OAuth token
        var accessToken = RequestItemsService.User.AccessToken; // Represents your {ACCESS_TOKEN}
        var accountId = RequestItemsService.Session.AccountId; // Represents your {ACCOUNT_ID}

        // Step 2: Construct your API headers
        var config = new Configuration(new ApiClient(basePath));
        config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        // Step 3: Create Tabs and CustomFields
        // Set the values for the fields in the template
        // List item
        List colorPicker = new List
        {
            Value = "green",
            DocumentId = "1",
            PageNumber = "1",
            TabLabel = "list"
        };

        // Checkboxes
        Checkbox ckAuthorization = new Checkbox
        {
            TabLabel = "ckAuthorization",
            Selected = "true"
        };
         Checkbox ckAgreement = new Checkbox
        {
            TabLabel = "ckAgreement",
            Selected = "true"
        };

        RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup
        {
            GroupName = "radio1",
            // You only need to provide the readio entry for the entry you're selecting
            Radios = new List<Radio> { new Radio { Value = "white", Selected = "true" } }
        };

        Text includedOnTemplate = new Text
        {
            TabLabel = "text",
            Value = "Jabberywocky!"
        };

        // We can also add a new tab (field) to the ones already in the template
        Text addedField = new Text
        {
            DocumentId = "1",
            PageNumber = "1",
            XPosition = "280",
            YPosition = "172",
            Font = "helvetica",
            FontSize = "size14",
            TabLabel = "added text field",
            Height = "23",
            Width = "84",
            Required = "false",
            Bold = "true",
            Value = signerName,
            Locked = "false",
            TabId = "name"
        };

        // Add the tabs model (including the SignHere tab) to the signer.
        // The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
        // Tabs are set per recipient/signer
        Tabs tabs = new Tabs
        {
            CheckboxTabs = new List<Checkbox> { ckAuthorization, ckAgreement },
            RadioGroupTabs = new List<RadioGroup> { radioGroup },
            TextTabs = new List<Text> { includedOnTemplate, addedField },
            ListTabs = new List<List> { colorPicker }
        };

        // Create a signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
        // We're setting the parameters via the object creation
        TemplateRole signer = new TemplateRole
        {
            Email = signerEmail,
            Name = signerName,
            RoleName = "signer",
            Tabs = tabs //Set tab values
        };

        TemplateRole cc = new TemplateRole
        {
            Email = ccEmail,
            Name = ccName,
            RoleName = "cc"
        };

        // Create an envelope custom field to save our application's
        // data about the envelope
        TextCustomField customField = new TextCustomField
        {
            Name = "app metadata item",
            Required = "false",
            Show = "true", // Yes, include in the CoC
            Value = "1234567"
        };

        CustomFields cf = new CustomFields
        {
            TextCustomFields = new List<TextCustomField> { customField }
        };

        // Step 4: Create the envelope definition
        EnvelopeDefinition envelopeAttributes = new EnvelopeDefinition
        {
            // Uses the template ID received from example 08
            TemplateId = RequestItemsService.TemplateId,
            Status = "Sent",
            // Add the TemplateRole objects to utilize a pre-defined
            // document and signing/routing order on an envelope.
            // Template role names need to match what is available on
            // the correlated templateID or else an error will occur
            TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole> { signer, cc },
            CustomFields = cf
        };

        // Step 5: Call the eSignature REST API
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(config);
        EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelopeAttributes);
```